# Remote web driver does not start - Selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run my selenium grid code on remote nodes but it always throw exception.

**hub :**

```
java -jar /home/bu/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub
```

it will listen on 192.168.1.106:4444

**node :**

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.106:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -host 192.168.1.132
```

it will listen on 192.168.1.132:5566

**Java Code:**

```
package example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest 
{

@Test
public void runFirefox() throws MalformedURLException
{

// We have to mention browser which we want to use for test execution
DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

// Set the platform where we want to run our test- we can use MAC and Linux and other platforms as well
cap.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);

// Here you can use hub address, hub will take the responsibility to execute the test on respective node
URL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.132:5566/wd/hub");

// Create driver with hub address and capability
WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);

// start application
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

// get the title and print the same
System.out.println("Blog title is "+driver.getTitle());

driver.close();

}

}
```

**node log:**

```
[root@lenovo u01]# java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/u01/driver/geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.106:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -host 192.168.1.132
16:46:38.669 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
16:46:38.670 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
2017-02-20 16:46:39.092:INFO::main: Logging initialized @656ms
16:46:39.124 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
16:46:39.124 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
16:46:39.124 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
16:46:39.124 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
16:46:39.125 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
16:46:39.125 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
16:46:39.126 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
2017-02-20 16:46:39.155:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2017-02-20 16:46:39.182:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5ae50ce6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-02-20 16:46:39.201:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@26e5b2bd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:5566}
2017-02-20 16:46:39.201:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @766ms
16:46:39.201 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
16:46:39.214 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
16:46:39.214 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.106:4444/grid/register
16:46:39.232 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
16:46:49.344 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
16:46:57.281 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}]])
16:46:57.287 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}]
Usage:
    /u01/driver/geckodriver [OPTIONS]
/u01/driver/geckodriver: Unknown option --port=10204
16:47:17.350 INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
16:47:17.360 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:86)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:10204 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:10204 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 36 more
16:47:17.373 WARN - Exception: Connection refused (Connection refused)
16:47:17.434 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}]])
16:47:17.436 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}]
Usage:
    /u01/driver/geckodriver [OPTIONS]
/u01/driver/geckodriver: Unknown option --port=25275
16:47:37.447 INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
16:47:37.453 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:86)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:25275 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'lenovo.gworks.mobi', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:25275 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 36 more
16:47:37.459 WARN - Exception: Connection refused (Connection refused)
16:47:37.489 WARN - Exception thrown
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:500)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.<init>(DesiredCapabilities.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.setJsonParameters(NewSession.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16:47:37.490 WARN - Exception: null
```

OS: Fedora 23, Firefox version 50.1.0, selenium standalone server 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

We need to change

From

> -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/u01/driver/geckodriver

To

> -Dwebdriver.firefox.marionette="/u01/driver/geckodriver"

e.g)

```
java -Dwebdriver.firefox.marionette="/u01/driver/geckodriver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.106:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -host 192.168.1.132
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("10.10.25.106:5554/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

Comment: I can't get what is the difference between your code and mine. I also did the same can you look at this `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;` . if remote driver is wrong, how can I get logs in remote node?

Comment: Did you comment your  URL line before trying? You will see the logs/erros on your console, or alternatively take a screenshot (bug wise)

Comment: Ok updated my post, this should work 100%, please comment your URL line before trying and let me know how it went! :)

Answer (score 0):

This command line to registry a node on window, that i solved the problem like your

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\web-driver\chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.firefox.marionette="C:\web-driver\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.114:4444/grid/register -port 5551
```